# Is there a dual to term "vacuously true" for a universal set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

For an empty set, any statement that claims "for all ... is true/false" are considered "vacuously true". So, can we construct a universal set in which any statement that claims "there exists ... is false/true" as a dual to the vacuously true statements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\forall x\in X.P(x)$ is usually<sup>1</sup> viewed as shorthand for $\forall x.x\in X\to P(x)$. With this definition, when $X=\varnothing$ then $x\in X$ is equivalent to $\bot$, the constantly false proposition. We then have (arguably by definition of $\bot$) that $\bot\to Q$ is always true. To this end, the universal quantifier isn't particularly relevant. $\exists x.x\in\varnothing\to P(x)$ is also always true.

If $\forall x\in\varnothing.P(x)$ is always true then $\neg\forall x\in\varnothing.P(x)$ is always false, which is to say (verify this) $\exists x\in\varnothing.Q(x)$ is always false. Again, this becomes $\exists x.x\in\varnothing\land Q(x)$ and again $\bot\land Q$ is always false.

There is no "universal set" in most set theories, but $\forall x$/$\exists x$ already runs over all possible sets.

<sup>1</sup> In type theory the story would be quite different.

Comment: The type theory story is not much different as $ \Pi_{x:U} \bot \to x $ is witnessed by the empty function.

Comment: @QthePlatypus There is no analogue to $\forall x.x\in X\to P(x)$ in typical type theories. That is, membership ($\in$) isn't a concept in type theory and so we can't explain bounded quantifiers this way. Instead, we take bounded (universal) quantifiers (Pi types) as primitives (in most dependent type theories). It does ultimately come down to the $\bot$ type, but the story is somewhat different, and perhaps less satisfying to explain. The story for $\bot\to Q$ always being "true" isn't very different and can be made identical.

Comment: Sorry, I needed to internalize some notation as well as fundamentals. But, yeah, your answer is actually very informative. Thank you.

Comment: @acarturk No need to apologize. I much prefer it when people take the time to actually make sure that an answer answers their question.

Answer (score 0):

Not without loosing consistancy.  Consider $\exists x : x \ne x $ a mathematical system like this would have bugs.

The idea of vacourious truth comes from the implication $ \bot \to \top $ whoes contrapostive is itself. so in a way the dual of vacorious truth is vacorious truth.